# How to use a variable with type <TSource>

Tags: c#, arrays, predicate

I am quite new to the syntax of c#.

I was declaring an array of `Process`: `Process[] myProc`, and I am trying to use the `Count<>` member.

I tried to use it like this:
    `if(myProc.Count() > 0)`
but it doesn't seem to work.

What should the correct syntax be?

Thanks.

Edit: The compiler error is: Operator > cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'

And to clarify, I am interested in the syntax of the function. Since `Count<>` is declared as 
`int IEnumerable<TSource>.Count<TSource>(Func<TSource,bool> predicate)`, I am confused on the syntax.

When I was using C++, a count of the `Vector` size would be something like `v.size()`, so I am not sure how should I handle this `Count<>`

Comment: Define: "doesn't seem to work".  Would you really expect your mechanic to diagnose your car if you went to him and said "It's broken, what's wrong?"

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" - so is it compile error, runtime exception or unexpected behavior? What error message do you get?

Comment: While "questions about simple things" are welcome, the question itself should be a good one. This includes typically about *15-30 Minutes of research* and **show** the results of this research in your question! Further Hints: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/  For starters, "does not work" is a very bad description.

Comment: I edited the question to include the specfic compiler error.

Comment: I don't understand your edit... What are you confused about exactly?  Count is a C# extension method on the IEnumerable interface implemented by all collection classes in .NET, and is packaged in the System.Linq namespace.  It's a generic function, which infers its types automatically, so you don't need to worry about the TSource, etc.. unless you are doing much more advanced things.

Comment: The specific error message will happen if you forget the parentheses after Count. So are you totally sure that you get this error message for the exact code which you show?

Comment: The types are inferred.  In this case, it's equal to `IEnumerable<Process>.Count<Process>()`.  The version you mention is an overload that takes a predicated function that allows you to define how the count occurs, but you're not using that version.  The generic types are not required, as the compiler can infer what they are and use the correct values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of the Count feature, you seem to be simply wanting to know if there are any processes.  You should instead be using the .Any() method.

Make sure you add a:

```
using System.Linq;
```

(this is the problem you are facing with Count as well, since Count is a Linq method)

Then, use

```
if(myProcs.Any())
{

}
```

The advantage here is that if there are 10,000 processes, then Count() must count all of them.  .Any returns true after it finds the first one.  This is far more efficient.

Alternatively, you can also use `.Length > 0` but I prefer .Any().

EDIT:

As JacquesB correctly points out, in the case of Arrays (and anything that implements ICollection, which arrays do) then the .Count() method has an optimization which will check if the type implements ICollection, and if it does call Length instead, so in this case any is no more efficient but I still prefer it as it's more semantically meaningful to me.

Comment: I suspect it's the using directive that was the problem. Whilst the `Count` explanation is great, it may be better for the OP if you elaborate on the missing using directive.

Comment: If myProcs is an array, the count is known, so it doesn't have to "count all of them". Using Any is more idiomatic though.

Comment: @JacquesB - Count is an IEnumerable method, therefore it doesn't know that it's an array.

Comment: Thanks. It does solve my problem. But I am more interested in the syntax. Please see my edit as above.

Comment: @Erik: The Count extension method is smart enough to check if the target implement the ICollection interface, and use the Count method from this interface, which is O(1).

Comment: @JacquesB - So it is... one of those details you know at one point and then forget...

Answer (score 0):

What may confuse you is that type parameters to methods are optional if the type parameter can be inferred by the compiler. Eg.

```
myProc.Count<Process>()
```

is equivalent to

```
myProc.Count()
```

Because the type of myProc is `IEnumerable<Process>`, the compiler can infer that the value of the type parameter `ISource` must be `Process`. So to state it explicitly would just clutter the code.

Now the signature shown in your question is actually a different overload than the one you are using. There is an overload of `Count` which takes a predicate function as argument, but in the code you are using the one without a predicate, which effectively look like this:

```
int IEnumerable<TSource>.Count<TSource>()
```